# Divide a polyline in multiples vertices in Autocad

Tags: autocad

I’m working with coastlines in Autocad. The coastlines are drawn with polylines. I would like to divide a polyline in order to have more vertices. For example, a polyline has 350 points and I would like that polyline will have 1000 points. I have tried to find a command in Autocad that does this task, but I have had success to find the way to do it. 
Does anyone a way to divide a polyline in different vertices?

PD. My problem is the opposite of this: [How to simplify a polyline in AutoCAD?](https://superuser.com/questions/263669/how-to-simplify-a-polyline-in-autocad/263742#263742)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in command for that. You need to find a LISP which does that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my [Segment Curve](http://lee-mac.com/segmentcurve.html) program or my [Add Polyline Vertex](http://lee-mac.com/addpolyvertex.html) program.